# Close command prompt window if any exception is thrown

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have created batch file and scheduled it for every 1 hour.

Below is the batch file script

```
set libpath=D:\Batch\Batch_lib
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\aspriseOCR.jar
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\aspriseTIFF.jar
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\cmb81.jar
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\cmbcm81.jar
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\cmbem81.jar
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\cmbicm81.jar
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\cmbicmc81.jar
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\cmbicmcup.jar
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\cmblog4j81.jar
set classpath=%classpath%;%libpath%\cmbsdk81.jar
set classpath=D:\Batch\Batch_1.jar
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -jar Batch_1.jar
exit
```

This batch file exceutes the runnable jar file.
After executing the jar  and after some time it throws out of memory exception and the command prompt window is never closed and it also doesn't starts the other command prompt after an hour.

So my concern is how can I close command prompt after it throws any java exception?

atleast it should get closed after an hour.

Comment: does the jar file return an exitcode after it runs?

Comment: You tested this using something like %libpath%\aspriseOCR.jar & %errorlevel%?

Comment: If the java program _terminate_ after the exception, then the line below it must be executed no matters how the java program terminate. If the java program does NOT terminate after the exception (I think this is the case), then there is no way to terminate the Batch program and close the command window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java outputs the excpetions to the error stream so you'll need to catch it with redirection to &1 :

`java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -jar Batch_1.jar 2>&1 | find "Exception" && exit`

this should work without wondering about the exit codes.